# How do I get the primary namespace in an assembly?

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces, assemblies

For example, if I get the namespaces in EntityFramework.dll using

```
assembly.GetTypes().Select(t => t.Namespace).Where(n => n != null).Distinct()
```

and then only list the namespaces with the minimum periods, I get the following two namespaces

```
System.Data.Entity
System.Linq.Expressions
```

However, System.Linq.Expressions is the namespace of an assembly that EntityFramework.dll is dependent on and not the primary namespace of EntityFramework.dll, which clearly is System.Data.Entity.

How do I distinguish between the 2?

EDIT: By "primary namespace", I am referring to the root namespace of the classes within the assembly itself and not its dependencies.

Comment: IMO I think there is no such thing as "primary namespace".

Comment: By "primary namespace", I am referring to the root namespace of the classes within the assembly itself and not its dependencies. I apologize if it is confusing. I will edit the question.

Comment: Yeah, What I mean is that's a convention, not something that exists as a concept.